# vim search replace including newline

Tags: regex, vim

I've been googling for 3 hours now without success.
I have a huge file which is a concatenation of many XML files.

Thus I want to search replace all occurences of `<?xml [whatever is between]<body>` (including those words).

And then same for `</body>[whatever is between]</html>` (including those words).

The closest I came from is

```
:%s/<?xml \(.*\n\)\{0,180\}\/head>//g
```

FYI If I try this:

```
:%s/<?xml \(\(.*\)\+\n\)\+\/head>\n//g
```

I get a `E363: pattern uses more memory than 'maxmempattern'`.
I've tried to follow [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines) without success.

Comment: Try `:%s/<?xml \_.*<\/head>//g`.

Comment: @stribizhev it seems to work! May I ask you to answer and eplain your answer, please? Thank you very much indeed

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match any number of symbols including a newline between `<?xml` and `<body>`, you can use

```
:%s/<?xml \_.*<\/head>//g
```

The `\_.*` can be used to match any symbols including a newline. To match as few symbols as possible, use `.\{-}`: `:%s/<?xml \_.\{-}<\/head>//g`.

See Vim wiki, [*Patterns including end-of-line*](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines) section:

> `\_.` 
>    Any character including a newline

And from the Vim regex help, [*4.3 Quantifiers, Greedy and Non-Greedy* section](http://vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy):

> `\{-}`
>   matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible

**UPDATE**

As far as escaping regex metacharacters is concerned, you can refer to [*Vim Regular Expression Special Characters: To Escape or Not To Escape*](http://jeetworks.org/vim-regular-expression-special-characters-to-escape-or-not-to-escape/) help page. You can see `}` is missing on the list. Why? Because a regex engine is usually able to tell what kind of `}` it is from the context. It knows if it is preceded with `\{` or not, and can parse the expression correctly. Thus, there is no reason to escape this closing brace, which keeps the pattern "clean".

Comment: When I try your second solution `:%s/<?xml \_.{-}<\/head>//g` i get `E486: Pattern not found: <?xml \_.{-}<\/head>`

Comment: Found it it's `:%s/<?xml \_.\{-\}<\/head>//g` I let you edit your answer, and thank you again **`8^D`**

Comment: Yeah, the first `{` must be escaped, I forgot to add that in the example.

Comment: ? Why only the first `{` ? and not the `}` too

Comment: Usually, it is not necessary to escape `}` since it almost always appears in an unambiguous position. The regex engine knows how to handle it. Isn't it the case here? It should work with an unescaped `}`.

Comment: It works flawlessly. Thank you for this explanation too (you can explain that in your answer too).

Comment: I added this explanation and provided another - I hope - helpful link.