# Vim regex for java block comments

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to learn regex but can't figure out how the following regex works.

It is used to identify java block comments like `/*blah blah*/`:

#### Regex

`\/\*\_.\{-}\*\/`

I know that

- `\/\*` at the beginning is for matching `/*` and
- `\*\/` at the end is for matching `*/`.

#### Issue

But I can't interpret `\_.\{-}`.

What pattern does this expression stand for?

Comment: regex is wrong.. It won't get the comments.. Did you test the regex?

Comment: It is a VIM regex. `\_.\{-}` matches any characters incl. a newline lazily (same as `.*?` in most engines). Note that `\_.*` matches any characters including a newline *greedily*.

Comment: @stribizhev: You say this is a VIM regex, but you marked the question as a duplicate of one about PHP/Perl/JavaScript/Python/Ruby/Java/.Net regexes . . .

Comment: If you want, re-close with [vim search replace including newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434640/vim-search-replace-including-newline/32434899#32434899). It is still an off-topic question. [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970). Seems like it is time to update the [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)!!! :)

Comment: i have tested it and it works

Comment: \* I meant to say *same as `(?s).*?` in most engines*.

Comment: In general case, you want a parser: imagine that you have a java string: `String s = "abc /* def */ pqr";`, note that `/* def */` is not a comment. Same problem is for `// /* abc */`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vim search replace including newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434640/vim-search-replace-including-newline)

Answer (score 0):

To match comments like `/*blah blah*/` you must use a regex like this:

`/\/\*\_.\{-}\*\/`

because`\/` is used to match simple `/` character, then `\*` for `*`, and `\_.` match everything, finally `\{-}` is non-greedy operator.